# The attitude of animals before and after fall

Tags: creation, relationships

According to the verse below I believe this is how it was in the garden of eden, and how it should be

> Isaiah 11:6
>
> The wolf also shall dwell with the lamb, and the leopard shall lie
>   down with the kid; and the calf and the young lion and the fatling
>   together; and a little child shall lead them.

Did the behaviour of animals to man and each other changed after the fall of man and as a result of the fall of  man?

Or were they influenced by our new nature and attitudes? Or have they been like they were from the beginning?

If they have changed, what are the obvious changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The usual disclaimer - this is the Young-Earth Creationist, Biblical Literal view, which is not the only view out there.*

Many Creationists, including Ken Ham, Kent Hovind, and others believe and teach that the relationship between *man and animals* was changed directly by God after the Flood.

Before the Flood, man was vegetarian only:

> **Genesis 1:29-30 (KJV)**
>
> 29 And God said, “See, I have given you every
>   herb that yields seed which is on the face of all the earth, and every
>   tree whose fruit yields seed; to you it shall be for food.
>
> 30 Also, to every beast of the earth, to every bird of the air, and to
>   everything that creeps on the earth, in which there is life, I have
>   given every green herb for food”; and it was so.

but after the Flood, man became omnivores.

> **Genesis 9: 1-3 (KJV)**
>
> 1 And God blessed Noah and his sons, and said unto them, Be fruitful,
>   and multiply, and replenish the earth.
>
> 2 And the fear of you and the dread of you shall be upon every beast
>   of the earth, and upon every fowl of the air, upon all that moveth
>   upon the earth, and upon all the fishes of the sea; into your hand are
>   they delivered.
>
> 3 Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you; even as the
>   green herb have I given you all things.

As to when the *animals became dangerous to each other*, the Bible doesn't specify.  Some suppose it was after the banishment from the Garden of Eden, some speculate that it was at the same time the relationship between man and animals changed in Genesis 3.  But Scripture doesn't say for sure.

[Answers in Genesis interprets Genesis 1:29-30 as stating that man and animals were all vegetarian](http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/nab2/are-biblical-creationists-divisive), which does appear to be the case from a plain literal reading of the verses.  [Kent Hovind claims the same thing](http://www.creationtoday.org/tyrannosaurus-rex-was-a-cannibal/).  So they would naturally assume that animals became meat-eaters after the Flood as well.

Comment: "after the flood" makes some sense, otherwise it wouldn't have been easy to get those wild animals into the ark

Comment: Your second quote is from chapter 9. I'd edit it, except it's saying edits must be a minimum of 6 characters!

Answer (score 3):

The context of this verse:

> The wolf will live with the lamb, the leopard will lie down with the goat, the calf and the lion and the yearling together; and a little child will lead them. The cow will feed with the bear, their young will lie down together, and the lion will eat straw like the ox. The infant will play near the cobra’s den, and the young child will put its hand into the viper’s nest. They will neither harm nor destroy on all my holy mountain, for the earth will be filled with the knowledge of the Lord as the waters cover the sea. (Isaiah 11:6-9 NIV)

Is not talking about animals, it is talking about personalities. I will attempt to De-Analogize.

> The viscous will live with the humble, the secretive and shrew will lie down with the pushy, the vigorous and the domineering and the full of life together; and a little child will lead them. The content will eat with the anxious, their young will lie down together, and the domineering will eat bread like the worker. The infant will play near dangerous places, and the child will put its hand into dangerous homes. They will neither harm nor destroy on all my holy mountain, for the earth will be filled with the knowledge of the Lord as the waters cover the sea. (Isaiah 11:6-9 De-Analogized)

But to answer the attitude of animals before and after fall, this I do not know. Except for that of man, that I do know. Adam was not depressed until he fell into depression because of the knowledge of good and evil.

Psychology helps to understand this with the stages of grief, after denial caused from knowing good or evil we fall to anger, bargaining, and depression (self anger), but through forgiveness offered by the death of Jesus we can bring ourselves to acceptance and we can return to the vine (John 15). Faith being the opposite of denial saves us from depression.

If animals fall to depression I do not know, I have seen sad animals, but mourning and depression are two different things. So deductively this statement can be built.

If animals become depressed, they they also have fallen, else their spirit remains pure.

So if you yourself are depressed or angry, know your lack of faith. For many you can hear it happen with a sigh. So when you "can't believe it" just believe and you'll be cool.

Comment: A very interesting viewpoint, I like it! However, could you please indicate some sources for it, whether you arrived to it yourself or there is some notable discussion about it.

Comment: (John 15), (Mat 8:12), (Mat 13:42), (Mat 13:50), (Mat 22:13), (Mat 24:51), (Mat 25:30), (Luk 13:28), (Luke 6:44), (Matthew 12:33), (Romans 11:19), (Romans 11:21), (Romans 11:24), (Isaiah 28:16), (Matt 7:24), notice the building being the people falling to depression, and how to know when the rock is going to come with the parable of the fig tree (Mark 13), either to send you to depression and anger or into the kingdom (Luke 12:39). So to prevent the fall we bind our desire to do evil (Luke 11:21), and have faith forgiving offending truths, the Kingdom of Heaven is in your face (Luke 11:17-20).

Comment: It will benefit you greatly to understand how each reading comes to the weeping and gnashing of teeth. For once you cast your anger away, circumcising your spirit, by believing that Jesus will fulfill the Law for you (Matthew 5:17). And you circumcise your heart by focusing on the truths that are around you instead of your desire to look at creation or build yourself up. And circumcise your flesh, by avoiding its satisfaction, considering it all to be buried with the Jesus. Then you will Live the Life, and God will be with you (Immanuel).

Comment: Actually, my question was about references for this interpretation (animals meaning personalities). Was it your idea/viewpoint, or did notable theologians also write about it?

Comment: I have to be careful deciding that I did anything. But Jesus often used animals to reflect personalities (Matt 7:15, Matt 25:32, 1 Peter 5:8)