Did the original sin cause some animals to be wild?
The Bible teaches that God created everything and when He beheld what he had created, it was good. Since the animals were created before us, and God beheld them and saw that every animal was good. I understand good in this context meant that every animal was good and they lived together in harmony, where the lion would pass close by the impala and would not attack. Is it safe to conclude that the original sin committed by Adam and Eve caused wild animals to be evil inherently and hence wild? This is because everything God created was good.
Genesis 1:31

God saw everything he had made: it was supremely good


Many have supposed this to be so. I am not sure how one would demonstrate it from particular scriptures. (Up-voted to cancel the unnecessary down-vote.)

@NigelJ, thanks for the upvote, trying to understand how the original sin impacted on the world as it is today.

Perhaps "evil" is a bit strong for animal behaviour.

@RayButterworth, one hundred million people die every year from snake bites, those people die as a result of evil snakes. The snake is an evil beast and the Bible does refer to them as so, the book of Exodus does say to drive evil beasts from the land

@SoFewAgainstSoMany — In English, "evil" has an implication of conscious immorality, and so is a poor translation. Animals are no more evil than a tree branch that falls off and lands on you. E.g. in Leviticus 26:6, NLT has "wild animals", NIV has "wild beasts", CSB has "dangerous animals", NASB20 has "harmful animals".

Would we count viruses among 'animal' evil ?

"I saw a python walking away from …" — Thanks for adding some humour to my morning.

What does "wild" mean?
If by wild you mean carnivorous then yes: before the fall everything/everyone was vegaterian.  (https://creation.com/the-carnivorous-nature-and-suffering-of-animals)
If by "wild" you mean not-tame:
On the 6th day three "kinds" of living creatures were created: Cattle(H929), creaping things(H7431) and beasts(H2416). From this I derive that some living creatures(beasts) were created "wild".

Also see: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9903/59520

one hundred million people die every year from snake bites, those people die as a result of evil snakes    That is a wildly inaccurate statistic.
Globally, the World Health Organization (WHO) estimates that 81,410 to 137,880 people die from snake bites each year

@Kristopher, the point is these snakes still kill men. Does that make them evil? I leave that to you to decide.

@RayButterworth, no further comment, I asked a question and you may want to save that energy for a real answer.

The Bible tells us that God created humans "in his image" but not so animals. Unless the idea is that the serpent deliberately sinned against his creator?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany snakes kill people, but they aren't evil because it's not an act of rebellion against God. On the other hand you can definitely argue that it's a result of evil, but that's our evil, not theirs.

@NigelJ "would we count viruses...?" If you mean w.r.t. "evil", yes and no. Viruses that cause disease are not functioning as intended in God's Very Good Creation; this malfunction is (at least indirectly) a result of the Fall. Like bacteria, however (which are essential to life!), there is evidence that they have other, beneficial functions. If you mean w.r.t. "animals", viruses aren't alive in the way Scripture defines "life".

@Matthew I do not know what w.r.t. means. But as to viruses I regard them as a judgment, especially in these last days. For seven plagues (viral ?) are predicted.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/are-animals-under-the-curse
Duplicate question

@NigelJ, you know you can ask a search engine, right? "What does WRT mean" > "with respect to". I suppose it's possible that specific viral outbreaks are judgments, but lots of viruses are harmless (or perhaps even useful), which suggests that as a class they have some other purpose.

This is a complex question, so let's break it down and answer it in parts.
Were animals wild before the Fall?
Animals were certainly "wild" before the fall, in the sense that they weren't domesticated. In Gen. 1:24, one of the categories of animals created is translated "wild animals" in NIV; the Hebrew word here (hay) is similar to the English word "beast" in that, depending on the context, it can either refer to animals in general or more specifically to dangerous/unruly wild animals. In this context, since it's a separate category from the "livestock" and "creeping things", the latter meaning should be understood. Domesticating the natural world was a task that God gave to Adam and Eve in Genesis 1:26 & 28.
Were wild animals dangerous to humans before the Fall?
From Romans 5 (in particular, verse 12) it is plain that people are subjected to death as a result of Adam's sin, and thus we cannot believe that animals might have killed people before the Fall. While there were wild beasts already in the world,  they were not dangerous to man yet. Mankind's strife with nature was a result of the curse God laid on us after Adam's sin (Gen. 3:17-19).
Did the Fall affect the natural world?
Yes, see Romans 8:18-25. The natural world is subjected to futility as a result of Adam's sin and God's curse. This futility is a major theme in the book of Ecclesiastes, see especially 1:5-9. Things happen all the time in nature, but with no apparent goal or benefit. As Paul explains in Romans 8, nature is groaning and eagerly awaiting the return of Christ, even as we ourselves are.
Did carnivory begin at the Fall?
There are many Christians who believe that it did, but that inference cannot be made from Genesis alone. One thing that is plain is that humans did not begin to eat meat as a result of the Fall. That's a common misconception, but reading the Scriptures carefully shows that actually the eating of meat was a gift from God, given after the Flood, over 1500 years after the Fall:

Then God blessed Noah and his sons, saying to them, “Be fruitful and increase in number and fill the earth. The fear and dread of you will fall on all the beasts of the earth, and on all the birds in the sky, on every creature that moves along the ground, and on all the fish in the sea; they are given into your hands. Everything that lives and moves about will be food for you. Just as I gave you the green plants, I now give you everything.”
~ Genesis 9:1-3

Eating meat is a blessing from God and not a curse from the Fall.
Genesis simply does not say when animals began to be carnivorous. Thus, Christians are divided over whether or not animals were carnivorous prior to the Fall. We must be somewhat cautious about assuming that our opinion of what is good for animals is the same as God's. As C.S. Lewis points out in Problem of Pain chapter 9, we do not know enough specifics about God's purpose in creating animals to say definitively whether or not it is "bad" for them to eat one another.
Therefore, those who believe that animals didn't eat one another before the Fall make more complex arguments to defend that opinion. They will point to some of the eschatological verses in Isaiah, namely 11:6-9 and 65:25, which show predator and prey animals living in harmony, and claim that these portray a restoration of the pre-Fall world. Therefore, there must have been no carnivorous animals before the Fall. (Irenaeus makes this argument in Against Heresies Book V.33, though his main argument here is eschatological, he clearly sees these verses from Isaiah as a literal restoration of pre-Fall creation.)
They will also argue that, because Romans 5 says that death entered the world through Adam, this should be taken to mean death in general (including that of animals) and therefore there cannot have been carnivory before the Fall.
On the other hand, Christians who believe that animals have been carnivorous from the beginning, will caution against inferring too much beyond what is said expressly by the Scriptures. Only human death is in the scope of Romans 5, and none of the Isaianic passages claim that a restoration of Eden is what is being portrayed.
When we observe the created world, we can see right away that every kind of animal has features designed to kill other animals, or to avoid being killed. Many plants also actively try to kill animals, and lots of organisms (especially fungi) are designed to eat the corpses of dead animals. Since animal death and carnivory seems presumed in the design of every organism, and Genesis 2:1-2 indicate that God finished creating everything by the 6th day (clearly pre-Fall), it would be natural to infer that animal death was always a part of creation. Augustine explains this in Book III.25 of On the Literal Interpretation of Genesis:

Someone is going to say: 'Then why do beasts injure one another, though they neither have any sins, so that this kind of thing could be called punishment, nor by such trials do they gain at all virtue?'
For the simple reason, of course, that some are the proper diet of others. Nor can we have any right to say, 'There shouldn't be some on which others feed.' All things, you see, as long as they continue to be, have their own proper measures, numbers, and destinies. So all things, properly considred, are worthy of acclaim; nor is it without some contribution in its own way to the temporal beauty of the world that they undergo change by passing from one thing into another. This may escape fools; those making progress have some glimmering of it; to the perfect it is as clear as daylight.

With the right perspective, we can see ecology itself as beautiful.
I myself would favor the latter view (i.e. that animal death was the original, pre-Fall design), but I respect those who think differently. It is not an easy question, and there are good arguments in both directions.

Excellent treatment. +1
